# protoc documentation in golang is pretty confusing

Tags: protocol-buffers, protoc

protoc documentation is very minimal. I often see something like this and I could not find any documentation.

`protoc -I routeguide/ routeguide/route_guide.proto --go_out=plugins=grpc:routeguide`

- What does plugins=grpc: do? Does it need to be used together with
  `go_out`? If so, this is pretty confusing in my opinion since
  `go_out` is supposedly just specifying the output directory.

https://github.com/golang/protobuf has this example.

`protoc --go_out=plugins=grpc,import_path=mypackage:. *.proto`

This is more confusing since it has additional `import_path`. 
Based on the documentation, `plugins=grpc,import_path=mypackage:` is considered additional parameter (since it is terminated by :) and `.` denotes the output directory.

Is it correct? I still do no know know what `plugins=grpc` and `import_path=mypacakge` do.

Answer (score -1):

How to write proto

```
syntax = "proto3";

message Request {
    int64 phone_number =1;
}

message Response {
    int64 phone_number = 1;
    string message = 2;
    int32 status_code =3;
}

service CreateService{
    rpc Service (Request) returns (Response);
}
```

To Generate code:

```
#generate gRPC-Code

protoc oauth2/proto/oauth.proto --go_out=plugins=grpc:.
```

For more know about the proto and gRPC those repos contains the basic to advance with good examples

https://github.com/SXerox007/gRPC-Remote-Procedure-Call-

https://github.com/SXerox007/protos-